# Laravel collection filter by condition and split

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection and each item has a `featured` attribute which is either true or false, so I want to get two variables `$featured` and `$unfeatured`.

I can do this:

```
$featured = $collection.filter(function($item){
   return $item->featured;
});

$unfeatured = $collection.filter(function($item){
   return !$item->featured;
});
```

But maybe there's a shorter way?

Comment: errr, tried using [`where`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where) ? something like `$collection->where('featured', '<>', true)` for unfeatured..

Comment: But in this case where does the same, I mean is there a way to split them or do I need to run `where`/`filter` two times?

Comment: well, for clarity purpose i'd go with two call approach.. if you insist to have one, perhaps you can group them instead..

Comment: Please update the best answer to the one below. @nick

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I know this is quite an old post.  Thought I would add this for folks coming to this from search.

Since 5.3 you can use the partition method like so:

```
list($featured, $unfeatured) = $collection->partition(function($item) {
    return $item->featured;
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-partition

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for taking your time to add this

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`each()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each) method

```
$featured = [];
$unfeatured = [];

$collection->each(function ($item) use (&$featured, &$unfeatured) {
    if ($item->featured) {
        $featured[] = $item;
    } else {
        $unfeatured[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: But maybe I'll go with:  `$featured = $locksmiths->where('featured', true)->sortBy('original_distance');` `$noFeatured = $locksmiths->where('featured', false)->sortBy('original_distance');` since it's a little cleaner.

Comment: Please update the best answer to the one below. @nick